# How to pass data and variables to new page with Push.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ratchet, push.js

I'm currently develop an hybrid app with the [Ratchet](http://goratchet.com/) framework. Within this framework, all links are loaded via Ajax with the Push.js file. Everything works fine for static pages, but how can I retrieve a page which is dynamically generated? How can I pass a variable, or even data, to the new page which will be loaded via ajax from push.js?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, what you need is to leverage the power of local storage. See here for a good introduction: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp